# Why is an inline if/else faster than a .get() in Python?

Tags: python, performance

I was reviewing some code earlier and the developer wrote an inline `if`/`else` rather than a `get()` to retrieve an element from a list if it exists (otherwise give it a default value). I decided to spring some `timeit` code on repl and was pretty confused by the result. The `if`/`else` takes 1/3 the time of the `get()`.

[Here is the repl code](http://repl.it/ar8), and below is the code in the repl as well as the result for posterity:

```
import timeit

D = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}

def ef(): return D['a'] if 'a' in D else 1

def gt(): return D.get('a', 1)

print "gt1", timeit.timeit(gt, number=10000)
print "ef1", timeit.timeit(ef, number=10000)
print "ef2", timeit.timeit(ef, number=10000)
print "gt2", timeit.timeit(gt, number=10000)
```

and the results:

```
gt1 0.0659999847412
ef1 0.0239999294281
ef2 0.0249998569489
gt2 0.0539999008179
```

and a visual of 10 iterations of the above `timeit` calls, where the result has been multiplied by 10000 for representation purposes

[image: visual of 10 iterations]

Comment: Why wouldn't it be faster? I'd almost always expect built-in language syntax to be faster than a method call.

Comment: You're correct in the assumption. I just expected a built in function to have lower overhead on a dictionary than a conditional where we have to reference the dictionary value.

Comment: Right, but the function is obviously going to have to reference the dictionary value too, right? Otherwise how would it return said value when the key exists?

Comment: Is this inside a tight loop during the critical path of the application?  If not, I can't imagine why you'd care enough to time it.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft it is

Comment: Do you have a tool to generate this chart?

Comment: @JohnSchmitt you'll laugh...but I used [this .gov thingy](http://nces.ed.gov/nceskids/createagraph/) to generate it because i didn't want to fire up pycharm or excel.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `D.get()` path includes an attribute lookup, and a method call:

```
>>> import dis
>>> D = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
>>> def gt(): return D.get('a', 1)
... 
>>> dis.dis(gt)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (D)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (get)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

The attribute lookup (`LOAD_ATTR`) especially slows things down.

If you remove the attribute lookup (and give the `in` test a local to work with), the field is evened out:

```
>>> def gt_fast(D_get=D.get): return D_get('a', 1)
... 
>>> def ef_fast(D=D): return D['a'] if 'a' in D else 1
... 
>>> timeit.timeit(gt_fast)
0.2174091339111328
>>> timeit.timeit(ef_fast)
0.2139298915863037
```