# Dictionary: Why is `in` faster than `.get()` while checking keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I wanted to check if the key exists in the dictionary. So, the usual method is to use the method `.get()`:

```
if some_dic.get('some_key'):
    return 'Yeah!, Key found'
```

There is also another way:

```
if 'some_key' in some_dic:
    return 'Yeah!, Key found''
```

Now, the question is why is the second method is faster? What happens in internally, it won't traverses the dictionary like a list, which should be slower, of course as no hashing:

```
if element in some_list:
    return 'got it'
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you add some benchmark / comparison results in your question that show `in` being faster than `get`

Comment: [This link might help you out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509261/why-is-an-inline-if-else-faster-than-a-get-in-python)

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder Yes, thanks. This question is duplicate then.

Comment: `in` only checks if key exist in dictionary or not where `.get()` can check the existence of key, and if key exist it returns value of it's key and if key not exist you can also set optional value  basically `dit.get('key', 'default-val')` is equivalent to `if 'key' in dit: return dit['key']`
`else: return 'default-val'`

Comment: @Gahan follow the link posted above.